# Can I wrap a whole stage of a declarative pipeline as groovy library function?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to add something like

```
myStage()
```

to a Jenkinsfile. `myStage()` is defined in a shared library and contains a whole stage. Is this possible? I read that I can put individual steps and whole pipelines into groovy functions, but are stages possible as well?

Comment: For a declarative or scripted pipeline?

Comment: Preferably declarative.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible for declarative (I don't believe it is) but it definitely is for scripted. The declarative model has a bunch of special Groovy compilation and interpretation  (as far as I know).

Comment: I tried by myself and have not found a way to make it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible for declarative pipelines.

Other parts of a declarative pipeline might be extensible through libraries, like `options`, but [it was said](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49135?focusedCommentId=326449&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-326449) that:

> For example, anything that contains an actual step execution (so steps, post, when (in part because of when expression and in part because it'd be a pain in the ass), stage, and stages (because stage contains steps and stages contains stage) would not be supported.

See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49135.

Also, [entire pipelines in libraries](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/10/02/pipeline-templates-with-shared-libraries/)  is officially supported since  [Declarative Pipeline 1.2](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18614531)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I thought the essential information was already in the answer "no, it's not possible to do what you ask". I will update the answer anyway because it was said already that for stages in particular, this will probably never happen...

Comment: Isn't it possible to use them inside `script {}` blocks? I think I've seen something like DSL Jenkinsfile: `... stage(...) { ... steps { ... script { foo() } } } ...`, where `foo` had `parallel('foo1': { stage(...) { ...} }, 'foo2': ..., ...)` or similar.